# Pandas dtype options error when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, parsing

I'm reading a file which has only 14 columns.
But when I read it I get

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
```

I'm not sure why I get this as I have only 14 columns.

Comment: like this it is hard to say, but once read into a dataframe, maybe have a look at the rows that have data in these 16 to 23 columns and you'll find out what's wrong with these rows

Comment: Are you missing a carriage return in the CSV file so rows are getting combined?

Comment: It might help if you show a sample of your CSV data

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, you probably solved it, I'll place an answer anyway.
This problem is often caused by not providing `dtype` dictionary on the read. My answer is based on [link DtypeWarning](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.errors.DtypeWarning.html). Since you have 14 columns why not do it for all 14 (not required though)?

Let's consider that the csv file has 5 columns with one being `date`.

```
date        a   b  i  f 
2022/03/29  A1  B1 3 3.14 
2022/03/28  A2  B2 5 3.33 
and lots of more rows
```

The example code would be:

```
dtype_dict = {'a': str, 'b': str, 'i': np.int64, 'f': np.float64 }
df = pd.read_csv('c:/path_to/csv_file.csv', parse_dates=["date"], dtype=dtype_dict)
```